# InMemory rows getting duplicated while adding them to ViewModel Lists

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm having issues with my context class that inherited Dbcontext. When I'm trying to pass objects from the Dbset to a List in a ViewModel, those objects are for some reason getting duplicated inside the Dbset inside the context class. Here's some of the code:

**FIRST ACTION**

```
public ActionResult LoginConfirmed(int id)
        {
            UserHomeVM Model = new UserHomeVM();
            data = new TempDB();
            InitializeTestData a = new InitializeTestData();
            data = a.PrepareData(data);
            Model.Blogs = new List<Blogs>();
            Model.Users = new List<Users>();
            Model.Users = data.Users
                .Where(b => b.Id != id)
                .ToList();
            foreach (Blogs b in data.Blogs)
            {
                if (b.UserID != id)
                {
                    Model.Blogs.Add(b);
                }
            }
            return View("Home", Model);
        }
```

**TempDB class**

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure;
using System;
using infinitymesh_test.DAL.Models;

namespace infinitymesh_test.DAL.Models
{
    public class TempDB : DbContext
    {
        public TempDB()
        { }

        public TempDB(DbContextOptions<TempDB> options)
            : base(options)
        { }

        public DbSet<Blogs> Blogs { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Users> Users { get; set; }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
            {
                optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(@"Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Database=EFProviders.InMemory;Trusted_Connection=True;ConnectRetryCount=0");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**initialize test data class**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Data;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure;
using System.Data.Common;

namespace infinitymesh_test.DAL.Models
{
    public class InitializeTestData
    {
        public TempDB PrepareData(TempDB model)
        {

                  var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<TempDB>()
              .UseInMemoryDatabase(databaseName: "Add_writes_to_database")
                 .Options;
                model = new TempDB(options);
                var service = new BlogService(model);
                Users a;
                a = new Users("Tim Johnson", 19, "tim@domain.com", "tim567", "12345");
                service.AddUser(a);

                DateTime q = new DateTime(2018, 1, 12, 18, 15, 33);
                Blogs M = new Blogs("Title1", "Summary123", "Content1234", q, 1);
                service.AddBlogs(M);
            return model;
        }



    }
}
```

There's plenty of more Users and Blogs I've added manually, removed those to save you the trouble of scrolling.

**ViewModel**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using infinitymesh_test.DAL.Models;

namespace infinitymesh_test.DAL.ViewModels
    {
    public class UserHomeVM
        {
            public Users User;
            public List<Users> Users;
            public List<Blogs> Blogs;

        }
    }
```

Basically, when the LoginConfirmed action gets going, after PrepareData function is ran, data has 14 users. After I do the toList() method below to insert all users who don't have that Id into the ViewModel's, the data's users get duplicated, and those duplicates get added to the viewmodel at the same time.
I'm really unfamiliar with InMemory and I'm not allowed to use a real database, so any suggestions would be very welcome.

EDIT: here's the service class as well

**SERVICE CLASS**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using infinitymesh_test.DAL.Models;

namespace infinitymesh_test.DAL.Models
{
    public class BlogService
    {
        private TempDB _context;

        public BlogService(TempDB context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        public void AddBlogs(string Title, string Summary, string Content, DateTime PublishedDateTime, int UserID)
        {
            Blogs newBlog = new Blogs();
            newBlog.Title = Title;
            newBlog.Summary = Summary;
            newBlog.Content = Content;
            newBlog.PublishedDateTime = PublishedDateTime;
            newBlog.UserID = UserID;
            _context.Blogs.Add(newBlog);
            _context.SaveChanges();
        }

        public void AddBlogs(Blogs b)
        {
            _context.Blogs.Add(b);
            _context.SaveChanges();
        }

        public List<Blogs> FindBlogs(int userId)
        {
            return _context.Blogs
                .Where(b => b.UserID == userId)
                .OrderBy(b => b.PublishedDateTime)
                .ToList();
        }

        public void AddUser(Users u)
        {
            _context.Add(u);
            _context.SaveChanges();
        }

        public void AddUser(string Name, int Age, string Username, string Email, string Password)
        {
            Users newUser = new Users();
            newUser.Name = Name;
            newUser.Age = Age;
            newUser.Email = Email;
            newUser.Password = Password;
            newUser.Username = Username;
            _context.Add(newUser);
            _context.SaveChanges();
        }

        public Users FindUser(int userId)
        {
            return _context.Users
                .Where(b => b.Id != userId)
                .FirstOrDefault();
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you use InMemory database?

I don't see usage of InMemory extension.

You should use extension in ConfigureServices, like

```
services.AddDbContext<YourContext>(options => options.UseInMemoryDatabase("SimpleDbName"));
```

Comment: PrepareData function inside InitializeTest class invokes it, this was the best solution I could come up with to populate the database. Sadly this also means that I have to invoke the function every time the controller is used.

Comment: @WhatAmIDoing 1. You should use this extension in Startup class, in ConfigureServices method 2. You should populate database on startup, not on LoginConfirmed action execution, because each execution is adding duplicated data 3. Inject TempDb via constructor, because you have 2 instances of TempDb and I am not sure that both of them work with InMemoryDb

Comment: So I move the prepare data function to the constructor of TempDB class?

Comment: You should move prepare data functionality to the point of start your application, you should seed data (seed test data) only once, for more details look up here https://garywoodfine.com/how-to-seed-your-ef-core-database/

Comment: @WhatAmIDoing Or more easier way here: https://forums.asp.net/t/2122687.aspx?How+to+Seed+Data+in+Core+